# cross-domain javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, cross-domain

I am producing a javascript-based widget.  Nothing complex just a few document.writes...

When I place it inline in the page it renders fine in all browsers.  When I place it externally and load it via `<script src="http://example.com/path/to/site"/>` it fails to render in Firefox and IE but not Chrome.

Anyone know why and a possible workaround?

Comment: Please provide more detail.  Where is the `<script>` tag?

Comment: u missed off the `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` is not needed in the `<script>` tag since JavaScript is presumed as the default scripting language in every browser. You only need it for VBScript (if there's still somebody using it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you should close it with `</script>` instead of XML-style.

Comment: somewhat amazingly in my opinion, this is the reason!

Comment: Yeah it's a rather silly one, but it's because (x)HTML pages are usually rendered with a HTML/SGML based render engine instead of XML, because most people serve them with a `text/html` content-type. I myself am used to typing `<script />`, but that's because I use XSL(t) for templates and the XSL library transforms it to `</script>` automatically so I don't have any problems.